# Sprites not loading on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite

I'm trying to create a game with sprite animation, but I can't seem to load both the animated sprite and the canvas at the same time. When the canvas loads, there is no error in the console but I can't see the sprite on the canvas. When I change the code around a bit (e.g. call "Sprites()" in the render function), the animated sprite shows up but the rest of the canvas is blank.

Here are the areas of code that I believe the errors are in:

app.js

```
/*
    Sonic class creates the player's character, Sonic the Hedgehog
    Parameters -
        x and y are the player's initial coordinates
        sprites passes in a sprite object to add animation
        speed is the pace of the game based on level
*/
var Sonic = function(x, y) {
    // set initial sprite/image
    this.sprite = Sprites;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    // set initial score to 0
    this.score = 0;

    // set initial life count to 3
    this.lives = 3;

    // initialize sonic as alive
    this.alive === false;
};

/*
    Update sonic's sprite to give the appearance of movement
    Parameter - dt, the time delta between loops
*/
Sonic.prototype.update = function(dt) {

    // Sprites();

};

/*
    Draw the player character on the screen in canvas' context
*/
Sonic.prototype.render = function() {
    // ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), 30, 250);
};

// create new instance of sonic
var sonic = new Sonic(30, 250);
```

sprites.js

```
var Sprites = (function(global) {

    var sonicSprite,
        soniceSpriteImg;

    // update and render sprite at same speed as browser redraws
    function gameLoop() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 760, 608);
        sonicSprite.update();
        sonicSprite.render();
    }

    function sprite(options) {

        var obj = {},
            // current frame
            frameIndex = 0,
            // number of updates since current frame was displayed
            tickCount = 0,
            // number of updates until next frame should be displayed
            ticksPerFrame = options.ticksPerFrame || 0;
            // number of frames in sprite sheet
            numberOfFrames = options.numberOfFrames || 1;

        obj.context = options.context;  
        obj.width = options.width;
        obj.height = options.height;
        obj.image = options.image;

        obj.update = function() {
            tickCount += 1;

            // reset tickCount once it is surpasses ticks per frame
            if (tickCount > ticksPerFrame) {
                tickCount = 0;

                // increase frameIndex if it is less than number of frames
                if (frameIndex < numberOfFrames - 1) {
                    // go to next frame
                    frameIndex += 1;
                } else {
                    // reset frameIndex to loop if out of frames
                    frameIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        };

        obj.render = function() {
            // clear the canvas
            // obj.context.clearRect(0, 0, obj.width, obj.height);

            // draw animation
            obj.context.drawImage(
                obj.image,
                frameIndex * obj.width / numberOfFrames,
                0,
                obj.width / numberOfFrames,
                obj.height,
                0,
                0,
                obj.width / numberOfFrames,
                obj.height);
        };

        // obj.render();

        return obj;
    }

    sonicSpriteImg = new Image();

    sonicSprite = sprite({
        context: ctx,
        width: 408.8,
        height: 117,
        image: sonicSpriteImg,
        numberOfFrames: 4,
        ticksPerFrame: 3
    });

    // start game loop as soon as sprite sheet is loaded
    sonicSpriteImg.addEventListener("load", gameLoop);
    sonicSpriteImg.src = "images/sonicrunningsheet.png";
}());
```

The full source code for this project is here (please excuse the messy parts, this is still in progress) https://github.com/alexxisroxxanne/sonicvszombies

The live page for it is here: http://alexxisroxxanne.github.io/sonicvszombies/

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Please add your code in your question, not link to somewhere (which may go 404 --- its a rule here on SO, in worst case scenario, this can be marked as spam and deleted.)

Comment: Also try to isolate where in your code the problem could be. Most people won't read through 1000 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I appreciate the advice! :)

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through Alexxis--probably too much for a Stackoverflow question! Anyway, sounds like you need to know when your drawing methods are being executed (and if they are failing to execute). Are you familiar with the F12 tools? You can code `console.log('I just executed the sprite draw method')` and that message will be displayed in the F12 Console window. That will give you an idea if your sprite drawing code is even being executed. Put `console.log` messages at important points in your app to see how the browser is executing your code.

Comment: I apologize for the amount of code here - this is my first question, so I'm not fully familiar with how to format these yet! I haven't used that trick to debug lately, thank you for the reminder! I know it has helped in other projects, I will try to use this to pinpoint the error!

Answer (score 0):

In the Sonic constructor you assign this.sprite to the result of the Sprites IIFE.

```
var Sonic = function(x, y) {
    // set initial sprite/image
    this.sprite = Sprites;
    ...
```

The Sprites IIFE doesn't return anything, so Sprites is always undefined.
I guess you want to return the sonicSpriteImg there.

```
    ...
    sonicSpriteImg = new Image();

    sonicSprite = sprite({
        context: ctx,
        width: 408.8,
        height: 117,
        image: sonicSpriteImg,
        numberOfFrames: 4,
        ticksPerFrame: 3
    });

    // start game loop as soon as sprite sheet is loaded
    sonicSpriteImg.addEventListener("load", gameLoop);
    sonicSpriteImg.src = "images/sonicrunningsheet.png";

    return sonicSpriteImg;
}());
```

In the Sonic render function you get the sprite from the resources. The resources only returns undefined there. The reason is because this.sprite isn't an img url like on the other objects (Zombie, Nyancat etc.), but an img object. So you don't have to get it from resources.

```
Sonic.prototype.render = function() {
    // ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), 30, 250);
    ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, 30, 250);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This will be very helpful next time I write a function that I expect a value from, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was fixed when I moved the variables sonicSprite and sonicSpriteImg outside of the Sprites function and into the global context, and then, in app.js, calling sonicSprite.update(); in Sonic.prototype.update() and calling sonicSprite.render(); in Sonic.prototype.render()